# Add prefix to all rows and columns efficiently

Tags: shell, awk

My aim is to add a prefix to all rows and columns returned from an SQL query (all rows of the same column should take the same prefix). The way I am doing it at the moment is

```
echo "$(<my_sql_query> | awk '$0="prefixA_"$0' | 
                         awk '$2="prefixB_"$2' |
                         awk '$3="prefixC_"$3' |
                         awk '$4="prefixD_"$4')"
```

The script above does exactly what I want but what I would like to know is whether there is faster way of doing it.

Comment: You shouldn't need to pipe awk into itself multiple times. Just add the statements in one call separated with ; e.g. awk ''$0="prefixA_"$0';$2="prefixB_"$2....

Comment: Why are you doing this in bash instead of in the SQL query itself?

Comment: `SELECT CONCAT('prefixA_', col1), CONCAT('prefixB_', col2), ...`

Comment: There's no need to wrap it in `echo`. Just `mysql ... | awk ...`

Comment: @Barmar Unfortunately this is just a small part of a much bigger pipeline of transformations so string concatenation in the sql script is not feasible

Comment: Please include sample input, and desired output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case you are willing to do it with `echo` + `awk` solution then you could do it in a single `awk`, where we could prefix values in a single shot, though I am not sure about your query but considering here fields are separated by space only.

```
echo "$<my_sql-query>" |
awk '{$0="prefixA_"$0;$2="prefixB_"$2;$3="prefixC_"$3;$4="prefixD_"$4} 1'
```

---

---

***EDIT:*** Adding a generic solution here, by which we could pass field numbers and their respective values to and it could be added to fields, fair warning not tested it much because samples were not given.

```
echo "$<my_sql-query>" | 
awk '
function addPrefix(fieldNumbers,fieldValues){
  num=split(fieldNumbers,arr1,"@")
  split(fieldValues,arr2,"@")
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
    $arr1[i]=arr2[i]$arr1[i]
  }
}
addPrefix("1@2@3@4","prefixA_@prefixB_@prefixC_@prefixD_")
1'
```